# How I can groupBy by date?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5.8.
I want to make a "group by" by date in the actual month. But the format of the raw date is not just Y-m-d.

```
public function caGraphique () {
        $actualDate = Carbon::now('Europe/Paris');
        $ca = Order::selectRaw('sum(total_ttc) as sum, prepare_date')->groupBy('prepare_date')->where('prepare_date',[$actualDate->year.'-'.$actualDate->month])->get();
        return $ca;
    }
```

format of 'prepare_date' in my DB

```
2019-06-07 12:59:51
```

This returns an empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve here but your query is wrong, the way you are using `where` statement, plus the format of provided value to match for `$actualDate` does not match with the one in DB either so you should modify your query to this:

```
$ca = Order::selectRaw('sum(total_ttc) as sum, prepare_date')->where('prepare_date', $actualDate->year.'-'.$actualDate->month.'-'.$actualDate->day)->groupBy('prepare_date')->get();
```

Also not sure if you are just fetching the result which matches a particular date then why do you need a group by with that ?

*Anyways, I hope it helps*